# css How can I make the background of a link behave like the link itself?

Tags: html, css

So clicking on the background of a link would open up the link, or hovering over the background would turn the cursor icon into a pointer icon.

EDIT: Here is my yucky code that I didn't bother to show at first because of shame.

```
a{
  color: #815853;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
a:hover{
  color: #e3ddce;
}

ul li {
  color: #e3ddce;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
ul li:hover {
  background: #815853;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}`
```

Comment: had you tried anything ?? show some efforts

Comment: make an "div" with an background and a  href outside

Comment: Sorry, I just started writing HTML and CSS yesterday, I know it's a dumb question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean like this?

```css
.clicky {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" _target="blank">
<div class="clicky">
click here
</div>
</a>
```

Comment: That seems to be what I needed. Time to stare at your code and try to understand what is happening since I can't read HTML or CSS.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.harshit {
  background-color: yellow;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" _target="blank">

<div class="harshit">
click me
</div>
</a>
```